# Hölder's Inequality and step functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Define functions $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \chi_{[k,k+1)}(x)$ and $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k \chi_{[k,k+1)}(x)$ where $\chi_ {[k,k+1)}$ is the indicator function for the given interval. Let $f,g$ be zero for all negative numbers. Also assume that the $a_k, b_k$ are non negative.

Does Hölder's inequality give us that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kb_k  \leq (\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k^p)^{1/p} (\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k^q)^{1/q}$? ($1<p<\infty$ and $p,q$ Hölder conjugates)

It would seem intuitively like this should be true.

Comment: If you assume $a_k, b_k \geqslant 0$ or add some absolute moduli, then yes.

Comment: @Vladhagen: But what do functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have to do with your question?

Comment: The product of f and g gives the product of the pairwise coefficients in series.

Comment: @Vladhagen: that's one way to look at it. But the proof for the continuous function version is essentially the same as for the discrete one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some absolute values in there (or need to assume the $a_k$'s and $b_k$'s are non-negative), but then this holds.